# How to toggle color of a movieclip?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Let's say I have a movie clip on stage. Every time this movie clip is clicked I want it to change color but if is click again I want it to recolor (becomes white again). To be more clear - it is white at the begin and with the first click I want it to become yellow, with the second click to become white again and with the third click to become yellow again and so on.

I just wrote the code for the first click but I can't think how to do the rest.

```
var myColorTransform:ColorTransform=transform.colorTransform;

half1a.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, changeColour);

function changeColour(event:MouseEvent):void
{
       myColorTransform.color = 0xD5E40D;
       half1a.transform.colorTransform=myColorTransform;
       addChild(half_number1a);
}
```

Comment: a famous duplicate question, but i see no warn and no close votes! amazing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or if you don't like typing to much:

```
var myColorTransform:ColorTransform=transform.colorTransform;

half1a.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, changeColour);
var cc:uint = 0; //current color.
var cl:Array = [0xFFFFFF, 0xD5E40D]; //list of all colors. 

function changeColour(event:MouseEvent):void
{
       myColorTransform.color = cl[cc = (++cc < cl.length)? cc : 0];
       half1a.transform.colorTransform=myColorTransform;
       addChild(half_number1a);
}
```

### Explanation:

Little bit of explanation as after I saw comment I realized that this could be confusing to less experienced programmers and we want to teach each other here ant not to do job for someone else.

So what is going on here?

**Basic setup**

We declare some array with colors that we want cycle our movieclip with(by?).

```
var cl:Array = [0xFFFFFF, 0xD5E40D]; //list of all colors.
```

No we want to know which color we are now displaying so we declare another variable which will store index of current color.

```
var cc:uint = 0; //current color.
```

If you are already confused see [Working with arrays](http://help.adobe.com/pl_PL/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7fdc.html)

Basically (with current value of `0`) we would access first item of the array `0xFFFFFF` by this:

```
cl[cc];
```

**The goal**

Now all we need to do each time we click the movieclip is just move the index so that it points to next item(color) in our array.
We could simply increment the value of our current color like that

```
myColorTransform.color = cl[++cc];
```

*Notice here the difference between `x++` and `++x`. Adobe has great [example](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#increment) of how this differs.*

and it would work but only until we reach end of array (obviously we don't want to increment our index anymore, we want it to go back to `0`)
And all the rest is about doing just that - resting index to `0`;

If you have no idea what this strange `()?:;`syntax mean. You would probably want to check this [this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#conditional) out - simply it's just `if...else` abbreviation but you may better think of it as a function returning some value.

So in out case `cc = (++cc < cl.length)? cc : 0`

Would be equivalet of writing something like this:

```
cc = nextIndex();

function nextIndex() {
    if (++cc < cl.length) return cc;
    else return 0; //else is redundant here - if "if" is ture then function will return "cc" and no other instruction are executed in this function.
}
```

**Summary**

So in summary what `myColorTransform.color = cl[cc = (++cc < cl.length)? cc : 0];` line does is.

1. increment color index.
2. check if new index is smaller than length of color list.

   - if true, set `cc` to `cc` (leave as it is)
   - else, set `cc` back to `0`
3. Pick color value from color list `cl` at index evaluated within `[]`.
4. Set `myColorTransform.color` to picked value.

---

**Answer to additional question.**

From the point we've just ended the `cc` value is storing index of new color so you can simply use it to access `cl` again without redoing this crazy stuff. For example, if you want to have simply a single mc, you can just use visible property:

```
function changeColour(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    myColorTransform.color = cl[cc = (++cc < cl.length) ? cc : 0];
    half1a.transform.colorTransform = myColorTransform;
    half_number1a.visible = cl[cc] == 0xFFFFFF; //check if current color is white and set it's visible state accordingly
}
```

*Note that if button is not added to stage fist, you wont see it, even if visible property is set to `true`.*

***More flexible solution***

Or another way of doing this would to to create parallel or multidimensional array. In simple scenario like this, parallel array should be better choice as it's easier to track and you don't need to change anything you've already have.
Basically the idea is to create another array where each value(in your case, movie clips is companion with color value at the same index:

```
var cl:Array = [0xFFFFFF,      0xD5E40D]; //list of all colors. 
var ml:Array = [half_number1a, null    ]; //movie clips list.
```

So if you have something like this, now your `changeColor` function would look something like that:

```
function changeColour(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    myColorTransform.color = cl[cc = (++cc < cl.length) ? cc : 0];
    half1a.transform.colorTransform = myColorTransform;
    if (ml[cc]) addChild(ml[cc]); //add child if exist.
    if (ml[cc - 1]) removeChild(ml[cc - 1]); //remove previous child if exist.
}
```

And that's it. Just remember that you need to fist movie clip on stage before you call to `removeChild()`

The nice thing about this setup is that you can add as many colors and movieclips as you like just by pushing new values to arrays :)

Comment: Now i have problem to attach with the colored movieclip my half_number1a movieclip which must appear only when the half1a movieclip is colored yellow. Is possible to help me with that too?

Comment: Pawel Audionysos you are great! Your explanation is sooooo helpful to me! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

I'd use ColorMatrixFilter:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filters/ColorMatrixFilter.html

```
var aMatrix:Array = [
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0xD5,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0xE4,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0x0D,
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0 
];

var aYellow:ColorMatrixFilter = new ColorMatrixFilter(aMatrix);

// Make object yellow.
M.filters = [aYellow];

// Make object normal.
M.filters = null;

function toggleColor():void
{
    if (M.filters) M.filters = null;
    else M.filters = [aYellow];
}
```

Comment: Thank you but this is too advanced for me!

Answer (score 1):

Untested but you can try something like this...

```
var myColorTransform:ColorTransform=transform.colorTransform;

var nextColor : String = "yellow"; //set with expected Next Color

half1a.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, changeColour);

function changeColour(event:MouseEvent):void
{
       if (nextColor == "yellow") { myColorTransform.color = 0xD5E40D; nextColor == "white" }
       else if (nextColor == "white") { myColorTransform.color = 0xFFFFFF; nextColor == "yellow" }

       half1a.transform.colorTransform=myColorTransform;
       addChild(half_number1a);
}
```

Ideally you should use a `Boolean` to set a true/false state then use the `If/Else` to set colors. If `true` then make white or else if `false` then set yellow.